# How to Use the Google Speech To Text API for Real-time Transcription Stream Audio

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform

I need to use C++ to transcribe real-time audio from my mobile phone, but there is no real-time transcription demo in the Google example.
This is an official example, but not real-time transcription, but based on a file, so who can help me find examples of real-time streaming recognition?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api

Comment: This looks like the documentation of the APIs that need to be called from real-time speech to text recognition ..... https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

Comment: Yes, but there is no C++ example here.

Comment: If we look at the sample that you provided in your original post, the data for transformation comes from a file.  If I understand you correctly, that is not what you want.  I think your puzzle needs to be split into two parts.  First ... if the data is not coming from a file, where is it coming from?  First solve that puzzle to the point where you have input audio as binary data.  Then the second part of the puzzle will be to use the supplied sample to transform replacing the FILE APIs with your own source of binary audio data.

Comment: Yes, the amount of audio comes from the phone, so I need to be able to transcribe it in real time, but the cpp-docs-samples example is transcribed files, not real-time transcription, so I want to find out if there is a C++ real-time transcription example.

Comment: I think we will find that the same API in the sample can also be used for real-time transcription.  In the sample the data comes from a file.  Replace that logic to be data coming from your audio input from the phone.  There isn't anything in the GCP APIs that will help with that though.  The GCP Speech To Text API starts with "... please provide a binary source of audio data.".   The GCP Speech to Text API doesn't concern itself with where that data comes from.  You are expected to provide it.   Solve the puzzle of how to get data from your audio on phone and feed that into Speech API.

Comment: My idea is the same, but I tested the example, the method of transcribing files, opened a separate line to write data, and then read it in a loop. Once read to the end, the data can no longer be read, even if continue to write data, it does not seem to be an example that can read while writing.

Comment: Or my test method is incorrect.